# Different aggregate function based on scope

Tags: ssrs-2008

How can I use a different aggregate (sum or avg) based on which group is being displayed?
Lets say I have something like this:
Group 1
    |------Group 2
                  |----- Group 3
             
       |-----Details ... . . . . . .

Group 1 & 2 should AVG, where as Group 3 should SUM

Can I use the scope in an expression

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly dodgy way.

Add both sum and average columns in the report, and set a visibility filter to hide whichever columns you don't want to see. You could even add a boolean field and use that for the visibility expression; that way, if you want to change the rules you can just change the data without having to mess around with the report...